# How to set retry count for Sidekiq with ActiveJob?

Tags: sidekiq, rails-activejob

From the Rails API, I found ActiveJob can retry_job interval:

```
my_job_instance.enqueue
my_job_instance.enqueue wait: 5.minutes
my_job_instance.enqueue queue: :important
my_job_instance.enqueue wait_until: Date.tomorrow.midnight
```

> http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/Enqueuing.html

But if I want to set retry count, such as Sidekiq's:

```
include Sidekiq::Worker
sidekiq_options :retry => 5
```

> https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling

How to do in this sample code?

```
class SiteScrapperJob < ActiveJob::Base
  rescue_from(ErrorLoadingSite) do
    retry_job queue: :low_priority
  end

  def perform(*args)
    # raise ErrorLoadingSite if cannot scrape
  end
end
```

Now I added this to my job class:

```
Sidekiq.default_worker_options = { retry: 5 }
```

But it seems not very good.

Answer (score 26):

As of Sidekiq 6.0.4 you can use `sidekiq_options` in an ActiveJob to set the `retry` option.

Comment: Thank you. What is `Sidekiq-specific`? Could you tell me how to use it in ActiveJob class?

Comment: The method `sidekiq_options` for one!

Comment: @MikePerham Has this changed in v6 with the introduction of `Sidekiq::Worker::Options`?

Comment: Parts of retry are still not exposed but `sidekiq_options` is a big step forward.

Answer (score 19):

You also might be interested in this solution which uses `serialize` and `deserialize` api to store the number of attempts.

```
class DeliverWebhookJob < ActiveJob::Base
  def serialize
    super.merge('attempt_number' => (@attempt_number || 0) + 1)
  end

  def deserialize(job_data)
    super
    @attempt_number = job_data['attempt_number']
  end

  rescue_from(ErrorLoadingSite) do |exception|
    retry_job(wait: 10) if @attempt_number < 5
  end

  def perform(*args)
    # raise ErrorLoadingSite if cannot scrape
  end
end
```

Take it from [here](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/Core.html#method-i-deserialize).

Answer (score 16):

Since Rails 5.1, there is a built-in way to do this using the [retry_on](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/Exceptions/ClassMethods.html#method-i-retry_on) method. It's a general ActiveJob method, so it will work with any queuing backend, not just Sidekiq.

For example, for your specific job you could do:

```
class SiteScraperJob < ActiveJob::Base
  retry_on ErrorLoadingSite, queue: :low_priority, attempts: 5

  def perform(*args)
    # raise ErrorLoadingSite if cannot scrape
  end
end
```

You can also set a constant wait interval or an exponential wait strategy, as explained in the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/Exceptions/ClassMethods.html#method-i-retry_on).

Comment: ActiveJob became surprisingly handy in rails 5. Thank you for this answer!

Comment: From the documentation, "If the exception keeps getting raised beyond the specified number of attempts, the exception is allowed to bubble up to the underlying queuing system, which may have its own retry mechanism or place it in a holding queue for inspection.". This means that it is not possible to use it to limit number of retries for a job unless you disable retries for sidekiq altogether and use only `retry_on`.

Comment: @PulkitGoyal That's a great point! So as I understand, this job could be retried up to 30 times (5 times by ActiveJob and a further 25 times by Sidekiq using its default settings)? That would make this really confusing IMO and so it's probably best to stick with the Sidekiq specific settings then.

Answer (score 4):

There is a [activejob-retry](https://github.com/isaacseymour/activejob-retry) gem which does the job

```
class SiteScrapperJob < ActiveJob::Base
  include ActiveJob::Retry.new(limit: 5, strategy: :exponential)

  def perform(*args)
    # raise ErrorLoadingSite if cannot scrape
  end
end
```

---

Another option is to use [sidekiq middleware](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Middleware):

First define job_options class-method which will be available in the subclasses:

```
class ApplicationJob < ActiveJob::Base
  def self.job_options(options)
    @job_options = options
  end

  def self.get_job_options
    @job_options || {}
  end
end
```

Add middleware which reads job_options from the jobs's class and writes them to the job item for sidekiq:

```
module Sidekiq
 class JobOptionsMiddleware

   def call(job_wrapper, item, queue, redis_pool)
     job = item['args'][0]['job_class'].constantize

     job.get_job_options
       .each{ |option, value| item[option] = value if item[option].nil? }

     yield
   end

 end

 # in sidekiq initializer

 Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
   config.client_middleware do |chain|
     chain.add Sidekiq::JobOptionsMiddleware
   end
 end
```

And finally

```
 class SiteScrapperJob < ApplicationJob
   job_options retry: 5

   def perform
     # your code
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 2):

See [here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/242109e872090c1214ff848ea409c3e2de2d994f/lib/sidekiq/worker.rb#L76) the defaults for Sidekiq. The attribute `retry` "accepts" a boolean value and not a number as you assumed.

From the merge of active_job into Rails this [other file](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/49c9f850fa3e2484e3aaf20b2479f61b1cc9375e/activejob/lib/active_job/queue_adapters/sidekiq_adapter.rb#L21) one can see that once again `retry` doesn't accept the number of retries.

What the [documentation says](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/49c9f850fa3e2484e3aaf20b2479f61b1cc9375e/guides/source/active_job_basics.md#backends-features) then is that per job you can define if the job retries or not.

I also tried to find if the `config/sidekiq.yml` file can receive this number, and seems like it can't.

Finally,

> If you don't fix the bug within 25 retries (about 21 days), Sidekiq will stop retrying and move your job to the Dead Job Queue. You can fix the bug and retry the job manually anytime within the next 6 months using the Web UI.

Comment: You're incorrect.  'retry' can be a number.  https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling#configuration

Comment: Your question's title says "with ActiveJob". The URL you sent is not from ActiveJob. The owner of the repo (@MikePerham) replied as well saying you can't

Comment: Thank you. I have add `Sidekiq.default_worker_options = { retry: 5 }` into my class. But seems work worse(retry much times one day!). The default retry times is 25. Then can't I customize it?

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/7a727c61cfd3f174d32e3a231b14833b61b897fe/lib/sidekiq/middleware/server/retry_jobs.rb#L23:L32) what the `RetryJobs` is. The code you added should be added to the `application.rb` and not to your ActiveJob subclass.

In case this doesn't work the way you want, just move all your jobs to app/workers/ (renaming the filename suffix to _worker.rb) and go the standard way (à lá Rails 3)

Comment: Thank you. Then if I don't want to retry, how to do?

Comment: If you don't want to retry, either you don't have a job (lol) or you rescue the exception inside the `perform` function

Answer (score 1):

FYI this problem has been fixed in the release of Sidekiq 6.0. You can have a look at the changelog here: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/Changes.md

But basically you can pass the same options by calling `sidekiq_options` with your options hash. Thanks Mike Perham.