# Rails 5 + ActiveJob + Sidekiq: Stop and log error after 10 retries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob

Trying to program a job that after 10 retries (from all exception types) will report a failure and die. Can't get it to work. Tried [this answe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44764801/437019)r and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38592564/437019) too. Neither worked.
The best solution would be to access `retry_count` from within the `perform` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're asking for is the `sidekiq_retries_exhausted` hook. It will be called once your retries are up and job will move to dead queue. Just set retries to 10 and implement that hook.

`config.death_handlers` might also be interesting.

See docs here: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Error-Handling#configuration

Comment: Does that work with the ActiveJob? I don't use `include Sidekiq::Worker`

Comment: It seems to me that the solution you need is from the same thread that you already looked at, but the one you didn't try (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48302041/4473406) using retry_on https://stackoverflow.com/a/48302041/4473406. You can retry_on StandardError to catch all exceptions and pass a block that will be called once the retries are up.

If you want the job to end up in the dead queue, then re-raise the error from the block and set retry to false on sidekiq level. Let me know if you'd like me to edit my answer.

Comment: retry_on StandardError is a good idea! I'll give it a shot. thank you